# ng-class in AngularJS form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am confusing by the following code about angularJS form validation. Please see the HTML form and JavaScript code below, It is sample code given be our instructor. What I do not understand is in this tag

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': feedbackForm.firstName.$error.required && !feedbackForm.firstName.$pristine }">
```

inside the ng-class ="{...}", the "feedbackForm" is the name of the form, but the "firstName" is the an attribute of the $scope.feedback object, as described in the JavaScript code. What mechanism that connect them together such that it can be access by "feedbackFrom.firstName"?

Beside, what are the "$error" and "$pristine" right after the "feedbackForm.firstName"? Is it an object predefined by AngularJS? And, again, how they can be accessed by using a period?

HTML form:

```
<div ng-controller="FeedbackController">
    <form role="form" name="feedbackForm" ng-submit="sendFeedback()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': feedbackForm.firstName.$error.required &&!feedbackForm.firstName.$pristine }">
       <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
       <div  class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng model="feedback.firstName" required>
        <span ng-show="feedbackForm.firstName.$error.required && !feedbackForm.firstName.$pristine" class="help-block">Your first name is required.</span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

related JavaScript code:

```
    .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };

     var channels = [{value:"tel", label:"Tel."}, {value:"Email",label:"Email"}];

    $scope.channels = channels;
    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;

    }])

   .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

    console.log($scope.feedback);

    if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel == "")) {
       $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
       console.log('incorrect');
      }
    else {
       $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
       $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };
       $scope.feedback.mychannel="";
       $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
       console.log($scope.feedback);
       }
     };
  }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit off.

The `feedbackForm.firstName` refers the form `feedbackForm` and the input field `firstName`.

The `$scope.feedback` object is refered to by ngModel and handles the model binding.

`$error` and `$pristine` are classes added by AngularJS to indicate the state of the input field.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a form with angular, a reference for every element within that form is created in the form object.

$error and $pristine are created by angular to signify the state of the form field. If firstName.$error = true then the value entered in the firstName field doesn't meet the validation requirements (e.g. length).  $pristine tells angular whether or not the form has been touched. This keeps a field from showing as invalid when the user hasn't entered any information yet.

tl;dr:

$scope.feedback.firstName refers directly to the input field, whereas $scope.feedbackForm.firstName refers to the input field as it relates to the form.

Answer (score 0):

it can be accessed with "feedbackFrom.firstName" because you have named your form with "feedbackFrom" and have name attribute on your input with the value "firstName".

As for the form object and its $error and $pristine, You have it in the doc right here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController